# Screen corruption on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: graphics, visual-artifacts

I have a graphical glitch that happens occasionally when watching videos on Chrome. The screen glitches as shown in this picture:

[image: visual artifacts]

I have a dual-boot setup with Windows 10, and do not see the issue there.

Specs:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- AMD Radeon R9 380
- Google Chrome 74.0.3729.131

Running `dmesg` I can see the following stacktrace:

```
[   17.919260] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 1046 at /build/linux-hwe-nVhLak/linux-hwe-4.15.0/drivers/gpu/drm/amd/amdgpu/../display/dc/dm_services.h:132 generic_reg_update_ex+0x126/0x150 [amdgpu]
[   17.919261] Modules linked in: aufs overlay intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek kvm snd_hda_codec_generic irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_hdmi ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd snd_seq_midi glue_helper snd_seq_midi_event cryptd intel_cstate snd_rawmidi snd_seq intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer joydev input_leds snd serio_raw mei_me soundcore intel_wmi_thunderbolt shpchp mei intel_pch_thermal mac_hid acpi_pad parport_pc ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj usbhid hid amdkfd amd_iommu_v2 amdgpu i915 chash ttm i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt nvme fb_sys_fops psmouse e1000e drm ahci
[   17.919285]  ptp nvme_core libahci pps_core wmi video
[   17.919288] CPU: 1 PID: 1046 Comm: Xorg Tainted: G        W        4.15.0-50-generic #54~16.04.1-Ubuntu
[   17.919289] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. To be filled by O.E.M./B150M-D3H-CF, BIOS F5 11/02/2015
[   17.919310] RIP: 0010:generic_reg_update_ex+0x126/0x150 [amdgpu]
[   17.919311] RSP: 0018:ffffbcf281cbf810 EFLAGS: 00010246
[   17.919312] RAX: ffffbcf281cbf830 RBX: ffff9f6535775680 RCX: 0000000000000001
[   17.919313] RDX: 0000000000012410 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffff9f652c48bc00
[   17.919313] RBP: ffffbcf281cbf880 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[   17.919314] R10: ffffbcf281cbf898 R11: 0000000000000001 R12: 0000000000000001
[   17.919314] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
[   17.919315] FS:  00007fc2465aca00(0000) GS:ffff9f6540c80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[   17.919316] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[   17.919316] CR2: 00005555ab0bd000 CR3: 0000000272b62006 CR4: 00000000003606e0
[   17.919317] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[   17.919318] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[   17.919318] Call Trace:
[   17.919344]  dce110_update_generic_info_packet+0x6b/0x470 [amdgpu]
[   17.919369]  dce110_stream_encoder_update_dp_info_packets+0x21a/0x220 [amdgpu]
[   17.919391]  dce110_update_info_frame+0x4e/0x70 [amdgpu]
[   17.919413]  stream_adjust_vmin_vmax+0xca/0xe0 [amdgpu]
[   17.919433]  set_freesync_on_streams.part.6+0xae/0x2c0 [amdgpu]
[   17.919453]  set_freesync_on_streams+0x22/0x30 [amdgpu]
[   17.919472]  mod_freesync_notify_mode_change+0x103/0x190 [amdgpu]
[   17.919496]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit_tail+0x47a/0xae0 [amdgpu]
[   17.919513]  ? amdgpu_bo_pin_restricted+0xa5/0x290 [amdgpu]
[   17.919515]  ? _cond_resched+0x1a/0x50
[   17.919517]  ? wait_for_completion_timeout+0x3a/0x140
[   17.919518]  ? wait_for_completion_interruptible+0x37/0x180
[   17.919524]  commit_tail+0x42/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
[   17.919527]  drm_atomic_helper_commit+0x116/0x120 [drm_kms_helper]
[   17.919537]  ? drm_atomic_check_only+0x456/0x570 [drm]
[   17.919561]  amdgpu_dm_atomic_commit+0x91/0xa0 [amdgpu]
[   17.919569]  drm_atomic_commit+0x51/0x60 [drm]
[   17.919572]  drm_atomic_helper_set_config+0x63/0xa0 [drm_kms_helper]
[   17.919578]  __drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x6b/0x120 [drm]
[   17.919584]  drm_mode_setcrtc+0x4e4/0x650 [drm]
[   17.919590]  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x190/0x190 [drm]
[   17.919595]  drm_ioctl_kernel+0x6b/0xb0 [drm]
[   17.919600]  drm_ioctl+0x400/0x470 [drm]
[   17.919605]  ? drm_mode_getcrtc+0x190/0x190 [drm]
[   17.919620]  amdgpu_drm_ioctl+0x4c/0x80 [amdgpu]
[   17.919623]  do_vfs_ioctl+0xa4/0x600
[   17.919624]  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x51/0x90
[   17.919625]  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x80/0x90
[   17.919626]  SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[   17.919628]  do_syscall_64+0x73/0x130
[   17.919630]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x3d/0xa2
[   17.919631] RIP: 0033:0x7fc243fd2f47
[   17.919631] RSP: 002b:00007ffec3a65f38 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
[   17.919632] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000000000000000d RCX: 00007fc243fd2f47
[   17.919633] RDX: 00007ffec3a65f70 RSI: 00000000c06864a2 RDI: 000000000000000d
[   17.919633] RBP: 00007ffec3a65f70 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00005555ab2a1160
[   17.919634] R10: 00007ffec3a66030 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 00000000c06864a2
[   17.919634] R13: 000000000000000d R14: 00005555aa5683f0 R15: 00005555ab2a1160
[   17.919635] Code: da 48 8b 07 48 8b 40 38 e8 78 21 5b f0 48 8b 75 a8 65 48 33 34 25 28 00 00 00 89 d8 75 22 48 83 c4 50 5b 41 5a 41 5c 41 5d 5d c3 <0f> 0b e9 20 ff ff ff 44 89 d0 41 bd 01 00 00 00 4d 89 ca eb 9c 
[   17.919654] ---[ end trace 10692a166a224305 ]---
```

Comment: I would suggest checking the temperature of your graphics chip. Did you notice anything else when it happens? E.g., a fan of your computer starts spinning loudly, etc. ? Also, when you are switching to the text mode (Ctrl + Alt + F1), is your picture remains distorted? Have you noticed anything in dmesg? (any errors, warnings, etc.?)

Comment: I've tried unplugging a monitor that was connected to integrated graphics, while the other two monitors remain connected to my graphics card, and I haven't seen the issue since, so this might be the issue. I still see the warning in dmesg so that might be unrelated.